# Unable to login in fb in android custom app through graph api for another account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I developed an android app which consists facebook login through graph api.

I created the new app in facebook developers from my account and corresponding app_id is configured in android. So here I am able to login with facebook with my account successfully.

But if I ask other user to login it is throwing below error.

App not set up: the developer of this app has not set up the app properly for facebook login

So what is missing here to make it login for all fb users.

Could someone please guide me to reach my intention. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Facebook login working on other's account you need to make it available in the facebook developer console.

> Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?

[image]

Turn that to yes and app is available to all the users.

Comment: Thanks a ton man..Now other users are able to log into my app.

Now I am looking for the list of friends who accepted my app and made a log in.

In the graph API tool, if I select the application as my app I am not getting any friends list. 

But If I keep the default graph API explorer as an app, I am getting friends who are using my app and also other friends who are using different apps.

So how to filter the friends who are using my app and by selecting my app in the application drop down.

Comment: @kavuru if this helps you then please accept my answer +1 would be nice too. As for your question in the comment I am unable to answer it because I have no experience in that. You could post a new question for that.